# Microscopic description of drag

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, physical-chemistry, drag, viscosity

It is well known that a fluid opposes the motion of a moving object and we can represent this resistance in motion with a force, which we call it drag.

Different fluids exert different drag forces which must be attributed to the different strength of the intermolecular interactions of each fluid.

**Mechanism**

When an object (e.g. a sphere) moves inside a fluid (e.g. water) it "breaks" the intermolecular bonds between the molecules of the fluid. Breaking the bonds increases the potential energy of the fluid. This energy increase must be come from somewhere and so the kinetic energy of the moving object must decrease.

Is the above mechanism correct? What I want to understand is what happens at the microscopic level that gives rise to the force we call drag.

Comment: Don’t you want a mechanism that operates when an object is completely submerged? Drag still occurs even when a moving object isn’t breaching a surface, no? It doesn’t look like much individual research has been conducted here.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Apologize, "enters" maybe wasn't the correct term.

Comment: Interesting question, but it would help to be more precise in your question. There is skin drag - friction between the molecules and the surface which is different depending on the roughness of the surface and form drag, pushing the fluid out of the way that would depend on shape  then other effects that might depend on lift, shock waves, or the details of the wake.  Stokes law might be something to look, it is useful in measuring viscosity, but ignores compressible flow. It would give you an idea of how the fluid behaves, but doesn't really get at your question about intermolecular forces.